# Structural description of LUT5 component based on LUT4 component

Tags: vhdl

Please tell me how to correctly describe the structural component of LUT5 on the basis of the LUT4 component, the problem is precisely in the correct mapping of ports.

```
Entity LUT5 is
Port(
  A,B,C,D,E : in std_logic;
  Z         : out std_logic;
);
End LUT5;

Architecture Behaviour of LUT5 is
Component LUT4
Port(
  A,B,C,D : in std_logic;
  Z       : out std_logic;
);
End Component;
Begin
   ??????
End
End Architecture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent a five input lookup table by using two four input lookup tables with a selector choosing between the outputs based on the fifth bit:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lut5 is
    generic (
        LUTVAL: std_logic_vector (0 to 31)
    );
    port (
      a, b, c, d, e:    in  std_logic;
      z :               out std_logic
    );
end entity  lut5;

architecture behaviour of lut5 is
    component mux2 is
        port (
            a:  in  std_logic;
            b:  in  std_logic;
            s:  in  std_logic;
            y:  out std_logic
        );
    end component;
    component lut4 is
        generic (
            LUTVAL:  std_logic_vector (0 to 15)
        );
        port (
          a, b, c, d:   in  std_logic;
          z:            out std_logic
         );
    end component;
    signal z0, z1:      std_logic;
begin
LUT4_0:
    lut4
        generic map (
            LUTVAL => LUTVAL(0 to 15)
        )
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => b,
            c => c,
            d => d,
            z => z0
        );
LUT4_1:
    lut4
        generic map (
            LUTVAL => LUTVAL(16 to 31)
        )
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => b,
            c => c,
            d => d,
            z => z1
        );   
MUX_2_1:
    mux2
        port map (
            a => z0,
            b => z1,
            s => e,
            y => z
        );
end architecture;
```

The generics are a method of delivering the lookup table contents from the top level of the design model.

Add it a small testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lut5_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of lut5_tb is
    signal a, b, c, d, e:   std_logic := '0';
    signal z:               std_logic;
    constant LUTVAL:        std_logic_vector (0 to 31) := x"A2201000";
    signal index:           natural;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.lut5
    generic map (
        LUTVAL => LUTVAL
    )
    port map (
        a => a,
        b => b,
        c => c,
        d => d,
        e => e,
        z => z
    );
STIMULI:
    process
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        for i in LUTVAL'RANGE loop
            (e, d, c, b, a) <= to_unsigned(i,5);
            index <= i;
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And we can see that it performs as a five input lookup table:

[image: lut5_tb.png]

You can count the bits across the z output over time using the added index signal and find the output reconstructs the 32 bit LUTVAL (x"A2201000").

Here's the missing bits and pieces:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux2 is
    port (
        a:  in  std_logic;
        b:  in  std_logic;
        s:  in  std_logic;
        y:  out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of mux2 is
begin
    y <= a when s = '0' else
         b;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lut4 is
    generic (
        LUTVAL:  std_logic_vector (0 to 15)
    );
    port (
      a, b, c, d:   in  std_logic;
      z:            out std_logic
     );
end entity;

architecture foo of lut4 is
    constant lut:   std_logic_vector := LUTVAL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
LOOKUP:
    z <= lut(to_integer(unsigned'(d,c,b,a)));
end architecture;
```

Comment: I have another small question.
If I want to describe the function of OR5 using LUT5, can I do it like this?
   OR5_1:
    lut5
        generic map (
            LUTVAL => LUTVAL(0 to 31)
        )
        port map (A || B || C || D || E, Z);

Comment: No. You want to change the contents of the LUT5 loop up table, in the example I showed with generic you could have a '1' wherever there is a one in the binary value of a index.  That means every index but 0. in the lut5_tb `constant LUTVAL: std_logic_vector (0 to 31) := x"7FFFFFFF";`

Comment: Ok, i got you, but how can I structural describe any 5-input logical function using LUT5, I mean OR5 or AND5, XOR5 e.g.

Comment: Write a function for each one that generates the LUTVAL, An XOR5 would be any odd number of inputs in the binary  equivalent of the index value produces a '1', and AND5 would be "00000001" (all 5 inputs are '1'). For an arbitrary expression for i in 0 to 31 loop, (E, D, C, B, A) := to_unsigned (i,5); and use A - E in the expression in VHDL. if the expression is true (or '1') then retval(i) := '1'; (variable A,B,C,D,E: std_logic; variable retval: std_logic_Vector 0 to 31;  This is essentially how expressions are mapped to LUTs. Some are a bit more obvious than others.

Comment: But do I have the ability to simply describe structurally any simple logical function using LUT? That is, just like the description of LUT5 using LUT4, but now for example the OR5 using LUT5.
Simply, I am now at the stage of studying the types and methods of description in vhdl.

Comment: And sorry for my dummy questions, I just started learning vhdl and I trying to figure out with all.